# Composition of inverse trigonometric functions with trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition

I found in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions) article a useful table showing the algebraic expressions for the composition of trigonometric functions with inverse trigonometric functions, along with a picture explaining where they come from. Among others,

$$\begin{align}
\sin({\arccos{x}})=\sqrt{1-x^2}, \quad \sin({\arctan{x}})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\
\cos({\arcsin{x}})=\sqrt{1-x^2}, \quad \cos({\arctan{x}})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\
\tan({\arcsin{x}})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}, \quad \tan({\arccos{x}})=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\\
\end{align}$$

What would be, instead, the algebraic expressions for the composition of inverse trigonometric functions with trigonometric functions, such as the followings? Could someone provide them or give a source where they can be obtained?

$$\begin{align}
\arcsin({\cos{x}})=?, \quad \arcsin({\tan{x}})=?\\
\arccos({\sin{x}})=?, \quad \arccos({\tan{x}})=?\\
\arctan({\sin{x}})=?, \quad \arctan({\cos{x}})=?\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Did you try Wolfram Alpha? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%5Barccos%5Bx%5D%5D

Comment: The expressions you want will be using logarithms anyway.

Comment: @Anixx OP is asking about different functions, e.g., https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin%5Bcos%5Bx%5D%5D

Comment: The first two are triangle waves: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $$ t=\arcsin(\cos(x))$$

then

$$-\frac{\pi}{2}\le t\le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

and

$$\sin(t)=\cos(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+x)$$

thus

$$t=\arcsin(\cos(x))=x+\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$$
or
$$t=\frac{\pi}{2}-x+2k\pi$$

we choose the the value in $ [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misread your answer---nevermind!